# ViewPager in CoordinatorLayout shrinks unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-appcompat, android-coordinatorlayout

In my Android app running on Android 5.1.1 I have a layout using a `Toolbar` with a `TabLayout`, and underneath is a `ViewPager`. All of these are put together in a `CoordinatorLayout`.

In the first page of the `ViewPager` is a `RecyclerView` serving `CardView` items.

**My problem is that my `ViewPager` keeps getting resized in a way so that my `CardView` list items are cropped.**

My main layout looks basically like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the first fragment served by my `ViewPager` looks like:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

This renders something that looks like this:

[image]

When clicking a button in my layout, I use `startActivityForResult` to invoke another activity, and when returning to my activity *sometimes* suddenly my list is cropped so that only half of the first item is visible:

[image]

After swiping horizontally to another pager in the `ViewPager` and then back, the problem disappears, so it does seem a re-layout has not been properly triggered. Pressing HOME and then resuming my activity does NOT resolve the problem though. Note that this happens even if I am not modifying my layout in any way, I am simply returning from a startActivityForResult call. And yes, it only happens *sometimes*... And I have no background threads running that could explain the apparent random behavior.

At first I thought it was the `RecyclerView` that had shrunk, but using HierarchyViewer I was able to find that it was actually the entire `ViewPager` that had shrunk to about half its original height.

I tried various hacks to get around this, including calling `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` on my entire view hiearchy, but nothing seemed to help (although swiping to another page and back again fixes it). Also, those are not the kind of solutions I want to resort to... Then I tried changing my ViewPager height to `wrap_content`, which did in fact solve this particular problem; after returning to my activity the first item in my `RecyclerView` is never cropped, and I can scroll down to the other items. However, now instead the very last item of my list is *always* cropped, as can be seen in this screenshot where the list is scrolled all the way to the bottom:

[image]

Since I am now at a point where I don't really understand what's going on, I need some help. What should I really use as the layout_height for my ViewPager, and - above all - why? To me, `match_parent` makes sense, but how should I be thinking here? Is there a rational reason my views got cropped when using `match_parent`, or did I in fact encounter a bug in `ViewPager`, `RecyclerView` and/or `CoordinatorLayout`? How do I make sure that my `ViewPager` consistently fills the entire screen area below the AppBar, and that my `RecyclerView` can be scrolled vertically to properly render all `CardView` list items?

Comment: `match_parent` will work because the layout behavior will place the layout child below the `AppBarLayout` at the time children are being layout.

Comment: Thanks @NikolaDespotoski but that does not address any of my questions. Using `match_parent` I encounter the strange resizing of the viewpager after returning from a sub-activity, that is the main issue.

Comment: Perhaps you could create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It doesn't seem a simple matter to reproduce this.

Comment: @karaokyo yeah I did include basically all layout code, but you are right. I will try to condense this into a MCVE, and hopefully someone's willing to look at it before the bounty expires...

Comment: Try keeping `layout:height` of `ViewPager` as `0dp` and add `layout:weight` as `1`

Comment: @JavaGhost `layout_weight` is applicable to LinearLayout, not CoordinatorLayout which is an extended FrameLayout. This won't help.

Comment: Did you checked out the view hierarchy in Android Device Monitor - View Hierarchy for UI Automator? There you can see what exactly happens - which view gets cut or maybe appears above. Start with it and let us know what you see there.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my question I did precisely that.

Comment: Also, if you look below you will find that I already found the problem to be a bug in appcompat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've experienced a similar issue when using an older version of the support library.

See these related issues:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176406
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176187

Make sure you're using the latest `Support library`, version 23.1 as of this writing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to these other issues, they do indeed look identical. Yesterday I did upgrade the support library with no effect, but there might still have been something wrong with my setup, because today I downloaded Android Studio 1.4 from scratch, grabbed a new SDK and re-loaded all the dependencies. Support library is now @ 23.1. And with this setup I am no longer able to reproduce the problem. I will mark your answer as the accepted answer since it actually solves the problem (my own answer merely used a workaround). Enjoy the bounty. ;)

Answer (score 4):

It turns out this is almost certainly a bug in `CoordinatorLayout` or  even more likely in `AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior`. In an effort to create a MCVE I realized it was the fact that my sub-activity had an IME on screen that caused the shrinking of the ViewPager - when my activity is resumed after `onActivityResult`, the `ViewPager` is shrunk as a result of reduced screen real-estate from the IME, but is never expanded again despite the fact that the IME is no longer being shown *and* the fact that the `CoordinatorLayout` is indeed expanded.

After debugging and stepping through `onLayout` and `onMeasure` of `CoordinatorLayout` and `ViewPager` I am now fairly sure that the `CoordinatorLayout` does not properly propagate the change in size to its children.

I found that I can "fix" the problem by calling `requestLayout` on my `ViewPager`, but only if the call is sufficiently delayed (10 ms never works, 100 ms works *most* of the time):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mViewPager.requestLayout();
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

This obviously isn't a robust solution, but after investigating some more it turns out I probably don't even need `CoordinatorLayout` since I don't really have any advanced scrolling behavior. So my solution will be to simply go with a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` as my root view group instead. Nice and simple, no need to complicate things.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I will however try to condense this into a simple example and file a bug with Google.

As to what I should use as the height for my `ViewPager`, my original use of `match_parent` still seems reasonable. The fact that `wrap_content` solved the problem (but caused other problems) is probably just due to inconsistencies caused by the bug.

Comment: It turns out this bug is indeed already fixed in the support library. Credits to @marmor for pointing this out in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33275205/1226020

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment just remove the frameLayout and make recyclerView parent...I hope it will work:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but no, this did not work. As I said, the entire **ViewPager** gets unexpectedly resized when my activity is resumed, even if it's set to `match_parent` - and changing the layout of one of the fragments used as child pages doesn't seem like it would help. Then again, I'm not ruling out that there's a bug in the app compat library here so it's of course possible that a change that doesn't seem to make sense could indirectly fix the problem, But unfortunately it didn't. What was your idea behind the suggestion?

Comment: why don't you try replacing your fragment then with another one you are using....or if you are calling an activity finish current activity first and then call it on back button pressed from called activity...

Comment: Well, that might work, but I'm not really looking for long-shot workarounds such as abandoning basic stuff such as  `startActivityForResult`. It might work, since my problem is apparently timing related, but it would make my code messier, I would have to handle more state, and the performance would probably suffer a bit.